# Duplicate folder and all contents within Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Working in VS 2022 on a Blazor Project.

I have a subfolder in components called "ApprovalFlow" and I want to duplicate that folder and call it something else like MultiSelect, and rename everything inside of the new folder to conform to the new name. For the life of me I cannot figure out how to do this.

If I copy and paste the entire folder, I get the following:

[image]

The structure of the files within the new renamed folder are not the same.

There has to be an easy way to do this.

Not really...

I went to the file system and copied the folder, renamed it and renamed the files inside the folder.

The result looks like this:

[image]

[image]

So far so good, but when I reopen VS after doing this, the solution explorer shows me this:

[image]

I understand that I haven't changed anything inside the three actual files yet, and that is my point. What do I have to do to get the structure correct, and the naming correct?

Is there a way for the IDE to refactor what is inside the code so that it conforms to the names I have given the files?

Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Vs just did what you told it. There’s no option that something inside a directory has to match the directory itself. You could write a batch file or create templates

Comment: Daniel, I appreciate your reply.  I have edited my question (please see above) to better explain what I want.

Comment: resharper has refactorings to help when the file and types inside do not agree